# How to order by between two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

in my program I have two queries (the result is to create a top), the first query gets the top position and who is in that position, for example the first position result would be something like:

```
POSITION: 1 ID: 203
```

Where POSITION is the position and ID is the user id, then in order to get the user name and not display the ID, I do another query where I enter all the tops ID's and the query returns me the user names.

The problem is that on the first query I'm able to get the top order but when I enter the ID's in the second query the info returned is in a bizarre order and I'm not able to know which username goes in which position from the top.

PS: the second queried table contains two columns (ID and USERNAME) and the first table also contains two columns (POSITION and ID).

Comment: It is better to provider sample table data and expected ouput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return all the data that 1st table  have no matter 2nd table contain or not
then you can use left outer join and the query should be

```
SELECT f1.id as user_id, f1.position, s1.username
FROM first_table AS f1
LEFT JOIN second_table AS s1
ON f1.id = s1.id
ORDER BY f1.position asc
```

But you want to see only data that both table have then you can use inner join
Then Query should be like below

```
 SELECT f1.id as user_id, f1.position, s1.username
FROM first_table AS f1
inner JOIN second_table AS s1
ON f1.id = s1.id
ORDER BY f1.position asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Join Query

```
Select B.username from table1 A Join table2 B on A.Id = b.id order by A.POSITIONID asc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ft.user_id, ft.position, st.username
FROM first_table AS ft
LEFT JOIN second_table AS st
ON ft.user_id = st.user_id
ORDER BY ft.user_id
```

Where `first_table` is the name of the table with the position and the ID, and `second_table` is the name of the table with the id and username.

With this query you will obtain all data you want (ID, Position and Username) with one single query to the DB.